# CSS3 :target not working?

Tags: css, transition, target, stretch

I have the following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Void Museum</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
        html * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            }
        #panel,
        #content {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            }
        #panel {
            left: -220px;
            width: 250px;
            background: #030;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
               -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
                -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
                 -o-transition: all 0.5s;
                    transition: all 0.5s;
            }
        #content {
            left: 250px;
            right: 0;
            background: #003;
            }
        #panel:target {
            left: 0;
            background: red;
            }
        #content:target {
            background: yellow;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="panel">
            LEFT PANEL
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            CONTENT
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And two questions :

- Why isn't the panel coming out when i click on it ?
- How could i force the `#content`  block's `left` property to 250px when `#panel` is targeted ? Should i change all this to use relative positions ? If so, how would i force `#content` not to overflow of the right side of the page ?

This code does work when i use `:hover` instead of `:target` so i assume there's something i don't understand about `:target`.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `:target` only works if you set `<a href="#panel">` as it goes to the element with the ID of the #. Read more here: http://css-tricks.com/on-target/

Comment: Any idea about my second question please ? :)

Comment: The css selectors are aimed at links, so there isnt one for while it is "clicked on" because that would mean the link has been clicked and you would be elsewhere. You need to do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JHLN4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because you are using `:target` as "is-clicked" or similar, which doesn't exist. In CSS, something that can mimic that behaviour is the following:

You make a href to an id (e.g. `#panel`) and then click it. Now you have a #panel on your url and can start using `:target`

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JHLN4/)

The text links to #panel, activating `:target` and allowing it to work as if it was "clicked".